# Error 500 deploying a DJANGO app on heroku, in everything except the index

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-postgres, whitenoise

#### The view with the index works perfect even with statics, but the other views show the error 500

```
The code of my urls.py is next:
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include("home.urls",namespace="home")),
    path('api/',include("api.urls",namespace = "api")),
] +static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and that one in my urls home folder (app folder)

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from home import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
app_name="home"

urlpatterns=[

    path('VerItems/',views.VerItems, name="VerItems"),
    path('VerAutores/',views.VerAutores, name="VerAutores"),
    path('AgregarAutor/',views.AgregarAutor, name="AgregarAutor"),
    path('AgregarItem/',views.AgregarItem, name="AgregarItem"),


    path('',views.Index.as_view(), name="index"),

]
```

And finally. settings file, I know that BASEDIR is not what every web shows it should be, but if I change it, the index does not work anymore

```
from pathlib import Path
import os.path


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
    'rest_framework',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'examen2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'examen2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {

    #    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

    #    'NAME': 'db_exa2',

        #'USER': 'exa2_user',

    #    'PASSWORD': 'exa2_user11',

    #    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',

    #    'PORT': '5432',
#    }
#}
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config

DATABASES = {'default':{

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',

        'NAME': 'dnb74q5rqcp7c',

        'USER': 'cjkzdvkrbdffbf',

        'PASSWORD': '42ce12501b0132835f5ec98a33017cda9e8a32d2e8929b618e7a226e17100705',

        'HOST': 'ec2-34-232-212-164.compute-1.amazonaws.com',

        'PORT': '5432',
    }}



# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "statics/",

]
STATICFILES_STORAGE= 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I dont think the problem is the static files and related, because my index shows well, but honesstly not sure, I have beenn with this problem for hours and dont know what to do now. Maybe I need ti change something with the urls but dont find it on web, so...

Here is the views.py:

```
rom django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic

from .models import Items, Autor
from api.forms import FormAutor, FormItem
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import requests
# Create your views here.
class Index(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name="home/index.html"

def VerItems(request):
    url= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ItemsGET/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    obj = response.json()
    context={
        "objs":obj
    }
    return render(request, "home/VerItems.html/",context)

def VerAutores(request):
    url= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/AutoresGET/"
    response = requests.get(url)
    obj = response.json()
    context={
        "objs":obj
    }
    return render(request, "home/VerAutores.html/",context)

def AgregarAutor(request):
    form = FormAutor(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormAutor(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nombre = form.cleaned_data['autor_nombre']
            anio = form.cleaned_data['autor_anio']
            sexo = form.cleaned_data['autor_sexo']
            nacionalidad = form.cleaned_data['autor_nacionalidad']
            url= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/AutoresGET/"
            payload = {
                "nombre":nombre,
                "anionacimiento":anio,
                "sexo":sexo,
                "nacionalidad":nacionalidad
            }
            response = requests.post(url,data=payload)
            return redirect("home:VerAutores")
    form = FormAutor()

    context = {
        "form":form
    }

    return render(request,"home/AgregarAutor.html/",context)


def AgregarItem(request):
    form = FormItem(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormItem(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.is_valid():
                nombre = form.cleaned_data['Item_nombre']
                anio = form.cleaned_data['Item_anio']
                valor = form.cleaned_data['Item_valor']
                nombreautor = form.cleaned_data['Item_autor']
                categoria = form.cleaned_data['Item_categoria']

                url= "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ItemsGET/"
                payload = {

                        "nombre":nombre,
                        "aniocreacion":anio,
                        "valor":valor,
                        "nombreautor":nombreautor,
                        "categoria":categoria,
            }
            response = requests.post(url,data=payload)
            return redirect("home:VerItems")
    form = FormItem()

    context = {
        "form":form
    }

    return render(request,"home/AgregarItem.html/",context)
```

Comment: Did you forget to add `.as_view()` in your `urls.py`?

Comment: it i neccessary to do it in every path? Im noob in this and worked just like that running in local?

Comment: Index is a class and the other ones are defs, so...

Comment: Show us your `views.py` for details

Comment: Okay, already edit the question with the code

Comment: It looks like your `requests` is failing or `request.json()` may fail. Debug your code by sending error details to your email look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#admins. Or you can set DEBUG=True to quick debugging

Comment: Okay I did it and get this error: Gonna try find the reason:                                               

ConnectionError at /VerAutores/

HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/AutoresGET/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f37986d0c50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have another file called urls.py in a folder named api, which is another app in my project

Comment: Well I made another project with everything in a single app and works fine, didn't find a way to do it with multiple apps. If anyone knows pls let me know